# Trying to install nginx on Google App Engine with custom runtime

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, dockerfile

I've been trying to deploy my flask application on Google App Engine but I haven't been able to install nginx inside the docker container.

I'm using a flex env with a custom runtime

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: custom
api_version: 1
service: dev
env: flex
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python

RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.6

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

ADD app/requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD /app /app

RUN apt-get -q update && \
    apt-get -y -q upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y nginx

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/app_engine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah && \
    echo "healthy" > /usr/share/nginx/www/_ah/health

CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

and this is the console log:

```
Step 9/12 : RUN apt-get install -y nginx
---> Running in 3990d1fb6405
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package nginx
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y nginx' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 100
```

Thanks very much for the help

Comment: I don't think its related, but you should remove the `threadsafe` from your `app.yaml`. That is a standard environment parameter that is not used in the flexible environment.

Comment: Thx for the information, I changed it now!